# Calculating intersection line between two semi-cicles based on proportional distance to their origins

Tags: geometry

I hope you can help me here. We are trying to create the curve or line that gets draw between two semi-circle polygons that have each of them an origin point and a given radious. As on below figure:

[image]

We have two semi-circle that intersect. We have the lat,long of the origin point (as we are drawing over a GIS map), the angle of the polygon (usually $120$ degrees although the example is shorter for better representation) and the radius of the semi-circle.

The line or curve that we are trying to get is that the points are exactly at the same proportional distance to their origins. For example, the following polygons, I have create their curves at $50\%$ of their ratio, $40\%$, $45\%$, $55\%$ and $60\%$:

[image]

If we continue this for all points in which the ratio of the points with respect to the distance to the origin is the same, the final curve would be something like this:

[image]

And the final polygons that we kept are those in which al points inside are relatively closer to their origin than the origin of the other polygon.

[image]

The question is, mathematically, how can I calculate this, given a point in space (lat, long) a degree (North 0) that indicates the bisector of the polygon (direction of the polygon) and a distance ratio for each polygon?

The Angle of the semi-circle is fixed to 120 degrees. What changes is the direction of the semi-circle, considering North as 0 Degrees (like is usually in GIS), and they can even have the same point of origin but different direction.

It is possible that what I am asking here has already a name in mathematics, in case I am going a complicate route to explain something that already exists and it is explain in geometry books or something.

In reality there can be multiple polygons overlaping each other, no necessarialy only two.

Comment: basically you are trying to find a set of points such as $d_1/d_2=r_1/r_2$ (where $d_1$ and $d_2$ is a distance to corresponding center). This relationship can be expressed algebraically.